# Multiple return of a method and tuple assignment

Tags: python, methods, tuples, multiple-return-values

Long story short:

This method is inside a class Analyzer in the other file:

```
def analyze(self, text):
    # Access tools of nltk
    tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.TweetTokenizer()
    # Defining couning score variable
    score_positive = 0
    score_negative = 0
    score_nuteral = 0
    # since the text is a list we itterate of the list element by element
    for tweet in text:
        tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(tweet)
        # Checking each token
        for token in tokens:
            if token.lower() in self.positives:
                score_positive += 1
            elif token.lower() in self.negatives:
                score_negative += 1
            else:
                score_nuteral += 1
        return score_positive, score_negative, score_nuteral
```

A function calls the method

```
def search():

    # validate screen_name
    screen_name = request.args.get("screen_name", "")
    if not screen_name:
        return redirect(url_for("index"))

    # get screen_name's tweets
    tweets = helpers.get_user_timeline(screen_name)

    # pass to analyze
    tweets = Analyzer("positive-words.txt", "negative-words.txt")


    positive, negative, neutral = tweets.analyze()

    # generate chart
    chart = helpers.chart(positive, negative, neutral)

    # render results
    return render_template("search.html", chart=chart, screen_name=screen_name)
```

The question is how to assign multiple returns via tuple:

`positive, negative, neutral = tweets.analyze()`

Comment: `positive, negative, neutral = tweets.analyze()` should work, you need to add the text argument to the call. Otherwise, can you share the error message?

Comment: What is wrong with what you are doing at the moment?

Comment: The problem may be that your `return` statement in the `analyse` method is not at the correct identation level.  It should be at the same level as `or tweet in text:`.  As for your question, your return send three values, and you assign three values when you receive it; it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I added the text argument to the call: positive, negative, neutral = tweets.analyze(tweets). But now I cannot figure out why the flask do not process Web page.